# How to get a bank account in UK (without proof of address)?

Tags: uk, money

About 10 years ago I took a contract job in UK (IT consulting) and found out after getting there that some banks were not willing to give me a bank account without proof of address. I did not have a proof of address because I was renting a furnished apartment (landlady was paying for the gas, water, and those things directly). That particular contract was always extended in 3-month steps so it felt too iffy to rent my own place.

I was eventually able to get a bank account with a local branch of the bank I had used in Finland.

Now I have been looking into a contract role in UK but I no longer have an account with the same bank as in the past (I have been living in USA and because of tax reasons found it easier to close my foreign bank accounts). So I was wondering if there are anything I can do to make it easier to get a bank account, if I choose to work in UK?

(As a side note, sometimes in the past when I had asked the employer if they can pay to my foreign bank account, it turned out that the answer I was given ended up being incorrect. So I was told it was not a problem to make payments for the wages to my foreign account, but once I was onsite they found out that they did not have the ability to do that.)

Comment: Questions that are about living long-term or working in another country are better for http://expatriates.stackexchange.com.  Indeed [your exact question has already been asked and answered there](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/85/how-to-open-up-your-first-uk-bank-account-without-proof-of-address).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source, moneyfacts](http://moneyfacts.co.uk/guides/banking/can-you-open-an-account-without-proof-of-address/)

> Foreign nationals working temporarily in the UK whose lack of banking or credit history excludes them being offered anything more than a basic bank account - national passport, or national identity card (nationals of EEA and Switzerland).

[From HSBC](http://financialplanning.hsbc.co.uk/article/90/how-banking-works-in-the-uk?HBEU_dyn_lnk=Planning_MovingToUK_UsefulArticles_Link2)

> It can sometimes be difficult to obtain a UK proof of address when you first arrive. If you need to open an account without a UK proof of address consider HSBC's Basic Bank Account.

[This question on expatriates discusses in more detail though.](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/85/how-to-open-up-your-first-uk-bank-account-without-proof-of-address)